# Manipulation events of MediaElement not fire when on FullWindows mode

Tags: windows-phone, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

When I set player not in fullscreen (player.IsFullWindows = false), event work normally but when change player to full screen all manipulation event not work. Anyone have solution?

```
                <MediaElement Name="player"
                              Margin="10,5" ManipulationCompleted="player_ManipulationCompleted"
                              ManipulationDelta="Grid_ManipulationDelta"
                              ManipulationMode="TranslateX"
                              >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce this scenario by enabling both the **IsFullWindow="True"** and the **AreTransportControlsEnabled="True"**. I think it makes sense, because when we are in the Full Window mode, it will go to the new layer named **FullWindowMediaRoot** instead of the **MediaElement**. Inside the **FullWindowMediaRoot**, it is the **MediaTransportControl**s. You can see that clearly by using the Live Visual Tree as following:
[image]

So when we are in the Full Window mode, we need to handle the manipulation event of the **TransportControls** instead of the manipulation event of the MediaElement as following:

```
public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        player.TransportControls.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.TranslateX;
        player.TransportControls.ManipulationDelta += TransportControls_ManipulationDelta;
        player.TransportControls.ManipulationCompleted += TransportControls_ManipulationCompleted;

    }

    private void TransportControls_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void TransportControls_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thank for help, I have another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36197262/display-a-textblock-over-mediaelement-when-in-full-screen

Comment: I have replied it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36197262/display-a-textblock-over-mediaelement-when-in-full-screen/36197563#36197563