# Display a TextBlock over a MediaElement when in full screen

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I have a `MediaElement` and a `TextBlock` next to it. But when I set `MediaElement` to fullscreen, this `TextBlock` disappears. Can anyone share a solution?

```
<MediaElement Name="player" Margin="10,5" AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" />
<TextBlock Margin="10"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I have said in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36181933/manipulation-events-of-mediaelement-not-fire-when-on-fullwindows-mode), when we are in the Full Window mode, it will go to the **FullWindowMediaRoot** layer with the MediaTransportControls. In this way the TextBlock will disapper, because there is no place to show the TextBlock. In order to let the TextBlock show, I will recommend you refer to [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/custom-transport-controls) to create a custom transport controls for the MediaEelement.